# String concatenation to match all possible characters in PHP

Tags: php

I have the following variables:

```
question_0, question_1, question_2.
```

Is there a way to access those variable using string concatenation like this: `question_(the expression to match all possible characters or numbers goes here)`?
To be more specific, I have an array in the following format:

```
[{"question_0":{"question_id":"0","type":"multiple_choice_single","title":"ss"}},
 {"question_4":{"question_id":4,"type":"multiple_choice_many","title":"ss"}}]
```

I would like to iterate over the array and access the `question_(whatever)`.

```
foreach ($response["questions"] as $value): ?>
    <tr>
       <th><?=$value->question_->question_id?></th>
   </tr>    
 <?php endforeach; ?>
```

my problem is that question_0, question_1 are not in incremental order like this: question_0,question_1,question_2. They are random numbers:question_0,question_4,question_8

Comment: Say what?? Please be more specific

Comment: do you want to store variable name in another variable? or maybe you want to use arrays

Comment: i have just updated my question

Comment: `foreach(json_decode($questions) as $question) { ...`?

Comment: Your array notation is not PHP but JSON. If this is what you have, then you don't actually *"have the following variables: question_0, question_1, question_2."*

Comment: maybe this is what you are looking for? `${"question_" . $x}` where $x is a counter in a loop?

Comment: Please provide more of your PHP code, notably where this "array" occurs and is used.

Comment: `for($x=0;$x<=10;$x++){ echo ${"question_" . $x}[question_id] }` @Don'tPanic

Comment: @trincot can you tell me what do you mean please?

Comment: The array you have provided is not valid PHP code. How do you use it? Show some code, and we will tell you what is going on.

Comment: foreach ($response["questions"] as $value): ?>
           <tr>
                   <th><?=$value->question_->question_id?></th>
           </tr>    
  <?php  endforeach; ?>

Comment: where $response["questions"] is the json formatted array..

Comment: OK, I provided my answer based on your last edit.

Comment: thanks so much...it was easier than i expected..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access those properties with [`json_decode`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php):

```
<?php
 ...
foreach (json_decode($response["questions"], true) as $value): ?>
    <tr> <th>
        <?=reset($value)['question_id']?>
    </th> </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

With [`reset()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.reset.php) you select the value of the first key, whatever it is (*question_xx*).

See it run on [eval.in](https://eval.in/576533).

Answer (score 0):

I think what you need is this:

```
<?php

$x1 = "X";
$x2 = "Y";
$x3 = "Z";
$x4 = "Q";

for($i=1; $i<5; $i++)
{
    echo ${"x".$i};
}
?>
```

you can refer to variables as `${"x"};`, you can concatenate within those curly brackets.

also please try to format your question properly, a bad question will yield bad answers, you can tell by the comments how many struggled to understand your question.

Comment: WAT??? You have unused variables $x1-$x4. what are they for?

Comment: This would allow you to iterate over different variables,
The question changed too many times.. I lost track of what OP wants.